# Data Binding WPF Property to Variable

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding, variables, mediaelement

I have a project in WPF 4 and VB.net 2010. I want to bind the volume property of a mediaelement to a variable in another module. Mind you, the variable is in the correct data type, so no conversion is necessary. How do I do this?

Comment: Can you give us a few more details? Generally speaking, a UI component is bound to a class called a ViewModel, which is an abstraction of the UI. This ViewModel contains variables (like Volume, for example) that are tied to UI properties. The ViewModel can be a class from anywhere, even from another module (if you're talking CAL modules here). However, if it's a random variable on a random class, then you're probably going to want to make a new ViewModel class of some sort and do a getter+setter combo around your variable from your other class and implement INotifyProperty changed.

Comment: Haha, I'm not skilled enough to be operating at that complexity yet. The mediaelement in in a WPF page, and the variable is in a public-scope vb.net module (the variable is also public scope). So, the getter+setter combo is probably the way to go. How would I do that? (reply in answer, please, so I can upvote ya if it works. :)

Comment: I'll need to know one more piece so that somebody can answer: how are you currently backing your view with data? WPF allows you to put code behind just like in WinForms, or you can bind a data type (the ViewModel class type) to a specific View.

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean (probably because this has been a long day, so pardon my n00bishness). With one irrelevent, isolated exception, all my data is stored in variables in the VB.net code behind each WPF window, with an occasional reference to a public variable in another module. All the data directly used by the WPF objects are in the code behind the object's window, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure that your code behind implements INotifyPropertyChanged.

All that is is a way to notify the UI that value for the Volume has changed and it needs to grab the new value on the binding.

The second thing is you'll need to somehow access the variable from the other module in your code behind, and then reference that in your code behind using a Property.

Now the trick is, when you set the property, you'll want to also call the notify property changed event.

```
Public Property Volume()
   Get
     Volume() = YourModuleVolume
   End Get

   Set(ByVal Value)
     YourModuleVolume = Value
             'Call NotifyPropertyChanged("Volume") here
   End Set
End Property
```

I can't remember if the code behind class automatically sets itself as the DataContext for the User Control, so you may want to drop in a "this.DataContext = this" or VB.NET equivalent in your constructor. Usually the DataContext is pulled in automagically from your ViewModel. Basically, that says to use the specified class (aka code behind) as the source for all data bindings.

Then in XAML it's a usual databinding.

```
<YourControl Volume="{Binding Volume}" />
```

As a side note, this is really not how one usually goes about setting up a WPF application, so this scenario's a little odd. If you plan to do much with WPF, you may want to look into Josh Smith's resources on MVVM - that's really the intended architecture of a WPF application.

Best of luck!