# How do I bind a WPF control to a VB.net property?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, mvvm, binding

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Data Binding WPF Property to Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533803/data-binding-wpf-property-to-variable)

How would I bind my module1 property to my WPF TextBox1?

WPF code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,146,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

VB.net code:

```
Module Module1
    ReadOnly Property tbBinding As String
        Get
            Return "Success!"
        End Get
    End Property
End Module
```

Below is code that I have been working on based on the feed back I have been getting and the reading I have been doing.
/#######Current code in progres (trying with a class instead of a module)#######/

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid DataContext="Class1">
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,146,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=tbBinding2}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,74,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Class1:

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Class1
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

    Public Event PropertyChanged As PropertyChangedEventHandler Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged

    Private Sub NotifyPropertyChanged(ByVal info As String)
        RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(info))
    End Sub

    Dim varField As String = String.Empty

    Public Property tbBinding2 As String
        Get
            Return varField
        End Get

        Set(value As String)
            varField = value
            NotifyPropertyChanged("tbBinding2")
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

MainWindow:

```
Class MainWindow 

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim myClass1 As New Class1
        myClass1.tbBinding2 = "Success!"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: @EsotericScreenName I have seen that question but I must be missing something because I have not been able to figure out how to do this. I must have some fundamental idea wrong in my head. I will continue researching but thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not setting the `DataContext` anywhere

WPF has two layers: the data layer and the UI layer. The data layer is `null` by default, and you can set it by setting the `DataContext` property of any UI objects. Bindings are used to pull data from the data layer into the UI layer.

So, if you say `MainWindow.DataContext = new Class1()`, then you are setting the data layer beind `MainWindow` to a new instance of your `Class1` object.

Writing `<TextBox Text="{Binding tbProperty}" />` in the XAML is telling WPF to look in the data layer for a property called `tbProperty` and use it for the `Text` value of the `TextBox`.

If you change the `tbProperty` in your `Class1` object being used as the `DataContext`, that change will also be reflected in `TextBox.Text` (providing you implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged`). And if the binding mode is set to `TwoWay` (default for `TextBox.Text`), then changes to `TextBox.Text` will also update the `tbProperty` in the data layer.

I actually recently posted an [overview of the `DataContext` on my blog](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/) if you're interested.

Comment: Thank you! This answer and your referenced blog post opened a wealth of understanding about WPF and binding. I have started experimenting with more complex combinations of bindings all thanks to you!

Comment: Small comment regarding statement - "Bindings are used to pull data from the data layer into the UI layer." . It is not accurate statement since you controlling flow of data by Binding.Mode property. For example it written here: http://geekswithblogs.net/mamta_m/archive/2010/07/04/wpf-binding-mode.aspx

Comment: Please refer to [this code-project post](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/650456/databinding-examples-in-wpf-for-vb-net)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. Refer to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229614.aspx#Y0) article for an example.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of binding to class `Class1` (a.k.a. the "view model") from XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:viewModels:"clr-namespace:MyApplication.ViewModels"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <viewModels:Class1 />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,146,0,0" Name="TextBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Text="{Binding Path=tbBinding2}"/>
        <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="192,74,0,0" Name="Button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Note that this XAML assumes that the `Class1` class is contained in the same assembly under the `MyApplication.ViewModels` namespace.

Comment: I get an error if I do this in a module. Can I only bind to properties of a class?

Comment: You should be using a class, yes.

Comment: How do I point the XAML to that property? Class is Class1 property is tbBinding as string.

Comment: Use the name of the property: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=PropertyName}" />`

Comment: :-( Do I need to add a source? Or add a datacontext somewhere?

Comment: Set the `DataContext` for your `Window` or `Grid` to the class containing the property.

Comment: Bernard-I have added what I have currently above in my question. It still does not work . . . would you mind helping a little further? I am so grateful that I am finally making headway with this thanks to your help.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a XAML example.